# Some random files were accidentally merged into my branch. `git revert` not working

Tags: git, merge

I noticed when looking at my branch on Github that about 40 files were somehow merged into my branch.

I backed up the actual files I was working on and saved them on my desktop and tried `git revert hash` and pushed. But the unwanted files still remain in my branch.

I reverted back even further - way back before they were accidentally merged in - but again the files still remained.

Seeing as this wasn't working, I decided to revert once more, back to where I was before I started the previous reverts. However, this wont work - I keep getting a message:

> "Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge."

but when I run `git status` there are no files to commit.

Regardless, I ran through the commit process anyway, but I still get the same error.

Would anyone know what's happening here? Is there anyway I can reset my branch back to a certain commit, seeing as `git revert` doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do `git reset --hard <commit id>`

Answer (score 2):

Use git log to find the hash of the commit you want to the remote to be at.

```
git log -p
```

to see changes, or

```
git log --graph --all --decorate
```

to see a tree. (Having that last one as an alias in your shell is very handy.)

Copy the hash.
Run a command like:`git push --force <remote> <the-hash>:<the remote branch>`
Ex:`git push --force origin 225ds5f2z2cdas5d2A5S5D1Z2X1SF2Zgs5s:master`

See if it helps